# Template conflict Angular Meteor 1.2

Tags: angular-meteor

I just upgraded to angular-meteor 1.2. I also upgraded the angular package. App won't start. I am getting the following error message:

```
**error: conflict: two packages included in the app (angular-templates and templating) are both trying to handle *.html**
```

I could not find a package named 'templating' when I tried to remove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I too ran into this problem today, and `meteor remove meteor-platform` solved the problem for me. Removing `meteor-platform` causes `templating` to also be removed from the project, which resolved the conflict. I hope this helps!

**EDIT**

There are two others which may require removal according to [Step 0 of the Angular-Meteor tutorial](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/bootstrapping); these are `blaze-html-templates` and `ecmascript`, if they happen in your package list. Angular-Meteor 1.2 has some important changes to how templating is handled.

Comment: Thanks. removing blaze-html-templates took care of the issue I was having.

Comment: Weird, on the meteor angular tutorials page they don't mention to remove blaze & ecmascript. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> meteor remove blaze-html-templates
>
> meteor remove ecmascript

Run the above command to remove these conflicting packages and your app should run fine .

Answer (score 2):

Meteor 1.2.x

find out what are packages you have

```
meteor list
```

it will list all the packages and then find template package

e.g blaze-html-templates etc ...

```
meteor remove blaze-html-templates
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove angular-with-blaze to clear this problem

```
meteor remove angular-with-blaze
```

It would be nice to have an option to list package dependencies as described in this [enhancement request](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4387).